# Navigation with sub-menu fade effect, Links broken - jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, tags, navigation, anchor

I have a navigation menu that works the way I want it to, but when I click on a link that is in the sub-menu it doesn't load the page. It will only start the fadeout effect. I dont know why the link will not load the page. If I turn off jQuery, it works fine. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
var delay = 100;
var fade = 400;

 $j(function(){
 $j('#access-navi li.sub').toggle(function(){
  $j(this).find('ul li a').each(function(i){
   $j(this).delay(i*delay).fadeIn(fade);
       });
   }, function() {
  $j('#access-navi li.sub').find('ul li a').fadeOut(fade/2);
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="access-navi" class="no-j" role="navigation">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="#">Code</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="/code/html-css/">Html.Css</a></li>
      <li><a href="/code/java/">Java</a></li>
      <li><a href="/code/jquery/">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="/code/php/">Php</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j(function(){
    var inner="";
    $j('#access-navi .sub > a').toggle(function(){
        inner=$j(this).parent().find('ul li');
        inner.each(function(i){
            $j(this).delay(i*delay).fadeIn(fade);
        });
    },function(){
        inner.fadeOut(fade/2);
    });
});
```

Oh I'm hiding LIs not LIs A in the `.sub` no point of hiding only anchors IMO
The faiding isn't happening but I'm not sure if that was a side effect or intentional behavior as you'll reload the page. I'm using `inner` variable to cache the result of this jQuery selector instead of reading it once again in the next toggle.

Let me know if you'll have any question, I'll gladly help :)

Cheers

G.

Comment: Oh wow that worked! im not sure actually what you changed? If you could explain it a bit that would be great! :] I still dont understand why it was not loading the page upon click though..

Comment: I'm using toggle only for <li class="sub"><a href="#">Code</a>
and you've used it for whole .sub, .toggle is preventing default action on the links